# Is Chicken's "Hard to Kill" bonus useful?

Tags: nuclear-throne

When Chicken's health reaches zero, she becomes headless for a small period of time where you can still attack and kill enemies. After that short period Chicken dies properly and you see the normal game over screen.

Is this just a fun bonus or can you do something useful during headless Chicken time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes if you find a medpack or kill an enemy with the Bloodlust mutation, you come back to life.

You can see it here :

Additionally, there's a second bonus related to the passive ability:

> While Chicken is headless, the Black Sword (Chicken's secret weapon) gets a massive damage bonus (deals 80 damage per swing instead of the normal 12) and has a much wider swing arc.

Comment: Any chance you could provide a timestamp?

Comment: Listen to the first minute. He shows it a few times but it will take me a bit to find it

Comment: It's most useful if you have one or more mutations that provide or facilitate healing:  
**Rabbit Paw** makes it more likely to find medkits. **Plutonium Hunger** draws them towards you, which can make up for the loss of camera control while headless.  **Bloodlust** directly heals you on some kills. **Sharp Teeth** may kill enemies with the retaliation damage and save you via medkits or Bloodlust procs.